# memcached not working xampp windows

Tags: php, memcached

```
include 'php/db.php';
$qry = "select * from dsb_online";
$result = mysql_query($qry,$link);

if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

   $s=array($row['fk_user_id'],$row['last_activity']);
}

$memcache = new Memcache;  
$memcache->connect('localhost', 11211) or die ("Could not connect");  

$version = $memcache->getVersion();  
echo "Server's version: ".$version."<br/>\n";  

$memcache->set('key', $s, false, 10) or  
die ("Failed to save data at the server"); 
echo "Store data in the cache (data will expire in 10 seconds) 
<br/>\n"; 

$get_result = $memcache->get('key');  
echo "Data from the cache:<br/>\n";  

var_dump($get_result);
```

I have installed memcached in my xampp. This is a test file i am running to test it.
The out put i get is

```
Server's version: 1.2.6
Store data in the cache (data will expire in 10 seconds) 
Data from the cache:
array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "3" [1]=> string(19) "2013-02-11 11:54:44" }
```

Now i modified the code like this to test whether data is retrieved from memcached

```
$memcache = new Memcache;  
$memcache->connect('localhost', 11211) or die ("Could not connect");  

$version = $memcache->getVersion();  
echo "Server's version: ".$version."<br/>\n";  


$get_result = $memcache->get('key');  
echo "Data from the cache:<br/>\n";  

var_dump($get_result);
```

result is

```
Server's version: 1.2.6
Data from the cache:
bool(false)
```

can anybody tell me why my caching is not working

Comment: I cannot see anything bad; however the cache expiration is really low... I am guessing you tried to bump it up to 120 seconds right? I mean in the first code, you set the value, get it right back and it works.

Comment: @ThomasPotaire: is it because my cache expiration time is low?

Comment: @ThomasPotaire:Thanks for pointing me in right direction. Pretty much new to memached :)

Comment: It worked? Memcached is great! I'd advise using the [Memcached library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcached.php) instead. You will be able to add multiple servers to your pool (among other things).

Comment: @ThomasPotaire: yes absolutely.But now the real problem, my application is fully built, i suppose i need to rewrite my code to use memcached.am i correct?

Comment: You don't have to use it; however `Memcached` provides more tools and it is very similar to `Memcache`: you make the call.

Comment: can u spare 10 mins in chat?